# Issue Retrieving Quiz Explanation via Telegram Bot API

Tags: python, telegram

I hope you are all doing well. I have encountered an issue that I’m hoping to get some insights on. I am currently working on a project where I need to use the Telegram Bot API to retrieve quiz results, including the explanations for the answers, from a Telegram channel.

Here’s what I’ve been doing:

I am using the getUpdates method to get the quiz results, which works fine for retrieving the quiz questions and results. However, I am unable to retrieve the explanations for the answers. According to the official Telegram API documentation, there should be a "solution" parameter in the PollResults object that contains the explanation. But, in practice, this field seems to be missing in the API response.

Here’s a snippet of my code for reference:

```
import requests
import json

bot_token = 'XXXXXX'
url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/getUpdates'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

if 'result' in data:
    for update in data['result']:
        #... (rest of the code)
        poll_data = poll_response.json()
        print(poll_data)
```

And this is a part of the response I get:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [{
        "update_id": 123456,
        "message": {
            "message_id": 100,
            "poll": {
                "id": "1234567890",
                "question": "Sample Question",
                "options": [{
                    "text": "Option 1",
                    "voter_count": 10
                }, {
                    "text": "Option 2",
                    "voter_count": 20
                }],
                "total_voter_count": 30,
                "is_closed": false,
                "is_anonymous": true,
                "type": "quiz",
                "allows_multiple_answers": false
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

As you can see, the solution parameter is missing. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is there something I am missing or is this a limitation or bug with the Telegram Bot API?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am facing the same issue using the Go Telegram API [Telego](https://github.com/mymmrac/telego).
Another difference is that I'm not grabbing a PollUpdate but that in my case, the bot command is a reply to a poll. The explanation is supposed to be in `Message.ReplyToMessage.Poll.Explanation` but it's `nil (None in Python)` because the API does not return that in the first place.
Did you find out anything more in the meantime?